# Validation error I cannot understand

Tags: c++, debugging

I am receiving an error during validation for the "price validation" in my tester program and I am unsure as to why. I will attach the Header/CPP/Tester below. Any help is appreciated! thank you.

HEADER:

```
#ifndef SICT_AMAPRODUCT_H__
#define SICT_AMAPRODUCT_H__
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorMessage.h"
#include "Product.h"

namespace sict {

    class AmaProduct : public Product {
    private:
            //Holds a single character to tag the records as Perishable or non-Perishable product in a file.   
            char fileTag_;
            //Unit of Measurement
            char unit_[11];

    protected:
            ErrorMessage err_;

    public:
            AmaProduct(char = 'N');

            //Public member functions

            //returns a constant pointer to the unit_ member variable.
            //returning function from Header as did not work in CPP
            const char* unit()const { return unit_; };
        /*  Copies the incoming value string into the unit_ string.
            Make sure copying does not pass the size of the unit_ array.*/
            void unit(const char* value);

            std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine = true)const;
            std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
            std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const;
            std::istream& read(std::istream& istr);
    };
}
#endif
```

CPP:

```
#include "AmaProduct.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

namespace sict {

    AmaProduct::AmaProduct(char tag) {
            fileTag_ = tag;

    }

    void AmaProduct::unit(const char* value) {
            strncpy(unit_, value, 11);
    }

    std::fstream& AmaProduct::store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine)const {
            file << fileTag_ << "," << sku() << "," << name() << ","
                    << price() << "," << taxed() << "," << quantity() << ","
                    << unit_ << qtyNeeded();
            if (addNewLine) {
                    file << endl;
            }
            return file;
    }

    std::fstream& AmaProduct::load(std::fstream& file) {
            char s[MAX_SKU_LEN];
            char n[20];
            double p;
            int t = 0;
            int q;
            int qN;

            file.getline(s, MAX_SKU_LEN, ',');
            sku(s);
            file.getline(n, 20, ',');
            name(n);
            file >> p;
            price(p);
            file.ignore();
            file >> t;
            if (t) {
                    taxed(true);
            }
            else {
                    taxed(false);
            }
            file.ignore();
            file >> q;
            quantity(q);
            file.ignore();
            file >> qN;
            qtyNeeded(qN);
            file.ignore();

            return file;

    }

    std::ostream& AmaProduct::write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const {
            if (!err_.isClear()) {
                    os << err_.message();
                    return os;
            }

            else if (linear) {
                    //setfill?
                    os << setfill(' ') << left << setw(MAX_SKU_LEN) << sku() << '|'
                            << setw(20) << name() << '|' << right
                            << setw(7) << fixed << setprecision(2) << cost() << '|'
                            << setw(4) << quantity() << '|' << left << setw(10)
                            << unit() << right << setw(4) << qtyNeeded();
            }
            else {
                    os << "Sku:" << sku() << endl
                            << "Name:" << name() << endl
                            << "Price:" << price() << endl;
                    if (taxed() == true) {
                            os << "Price after tax:" << (TAX + 1) * price() << endl;
                    }
                    else {
                            os << "Price after tax: N/A" << endl;
                    }

                    os << "Quantity on hand:" << quantity() << " " << unit() << endl
                            << "Quantity needed:" << qtyNeeded();

            }
            return os;

    }

    std::istream& AmaProduct::read(std::istream& istr) {
            char s[MAX_SKU_LEN];
            char n[20];
            char u[11];
            char t;
            double p;
            int q;
            int qN;

            if (istr.fail() == false) {
                    cout << "Sku: ";
                    istr.getline(s, MAX_SKU_LEN, '\n');
                    //false or ! ******
                    if (istr.fail() == false) {
                            sku(s);
                    }

                    cout << "Name: ";
                    istr.getline(n, 20, '\n');
                    if (istr.fail() == false) {
                            name(n);
                    }

                    cout << "Unit: ";
                    istr.getline(u, 11, '\n');
                    if (istr.fail() == false) {
                            unit(u);
                    }

                    cout << "Taxed? (y/n): ";
                    istr >> t;
                    if (t == 'Y' || t == 'y') {
                            taxed(true);
                    }
                    else if (t == 'N' || t == 'n') {
                            taxed(false);
                    }
                    else {
                            err_.message("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable");
                            istr.setstate(ios::failbit);
                    }

                    if (err_.isClear()) {
                            cout << "Price: ";
                            istr >> p;
                            if (istr.fail()) {
                                    err_.message("Invalid Price Entry");
                            }
                            else {
                                    price(p);
                            }

                    }
                    if (err_.isClear()){
                            cout << "Quantity On hand: ";
                            istr >> q;
                            if (istr.fail()) {
                                    err_.message("Invalid Quantity Entry");
                            }
                            else {
                                    quantity(q);
                            }

                    }
                    if (err_.isClear()) {
                            cout << "Quantity Needed: ";
                            istr >> qN;
                            if (istr.fail()) {
                                    err_.message("Invalid Quantity Needed Entry");
                            }
                            else {
                                    qtyNeeded(qN);
                            }
                    }

            }
            return istr;

    }

  }
```

TESTER:

```
#include "AmaProduct.h"
using namespace sict;
using namespace std;
void piv(const char* sku, const char* name, const char* unit = "", char Tx = '\0',
    const char* price = "", const char* qty = "", const char* qtyNd = "",
    const char* date = "") {
    cout
            << "Enter the following: " << endl
            << "Sku: " << sku << endl
            << "Name: " << name << endl
            << "Unit: " << unit << endl;
    if (Tx) cout << "Taxed: " << Tx << endl;
    if (price[0]) cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
    if (qty[0]) cout << "Quantity on hand: " << qty << endl;
    if (qtyNd[0]) cout << "Quantity needed: " << qtyNd << endl;
    if (date[0]) cout << "Expiry date: " << date << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
void dumpFile(const char* fname) {
    ifstream f(fname);
    char ch;
    while (!f.get(ch).fail()) {
            cout.put(ch);
    }
    f.clear();
    f.close();
}
void _pause() {
    cout << "****press enter to continue...";
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
}

int main() {
    fstream prdfile("amaPrd.txt", ios::out);
    AmaProduct amaPrd;
    bool ok = true;
    int i;
    cout << "--AmaProduct test:" << endl;
    cout << "----Taxed validation test:" << endl;
    piv("abc", "abc", "abc", 'a');
    cin >> amaPrd;
    if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
            cout << "Passed!" << endl
                    << "Message shoule be:  Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable" << endl
                    << "Your Error message: " << amaPrd << endl;
    }
    else {
            ok = false;
            cout << "Taxed validation failed" << endl;
    }
    _pause();
    if (ok) {
            cout << "----Price validation test:" << endl;
            piv("abc", "abc", "abc", 'y', "abc");
            cin >> amaPrd;
            if (cin.fail()) {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
                    cout << "Passed!" << endl
                            << "Message shoule be:  Invalid Price Entry" << endl
                            << "Your Error message: " << amaPrd << endl;
            }
            else {
                    ok = false;
                    cout << "Price validation failed" << endl;
            }
            _pause();
    }
    if (ok) {
            cout << "----Quantity validation test:" << endl;
            piv("abc", "abc", "abc", 'y', "10", "abc");
            cin >> amaPrd;
            if (cin.fail()) {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
                    cout << "Passed!" << endl
                            << "Message shoule be:  Invalid Quantity Entry" << endl
                            << "Your Error message: " << amaPrd << endl;
            }
            else {
                    ok = false;
                    cout << "Quantity validaton failed" << endl;
            }
    }
    _pause();
    if (ok) {
            cout << "----Quantity Needed validation test:" << endl;
            piv("abc", "abc", "abc", 'y', "10", "10", "abc");
            cin >> amaPrd;
            if (cin.fail()) {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
                    cout << "Passed!" << endl
                            << "Message shoule be:  Invalid Quantity Needed Entry" << endl
                            << "Your Error message: " << amaPrd << endl;
            }
            else {
                    ok = false;
                    cout << "Quantity Needed validaton failed" << endl;
            }
    }
    _pause();
    if (ok) {
            cout << "----Display test, the output of the Program and yours must match:" << endl;
            piv("1234", "box", "kg", 'y', "123.45", "1", "5");
            cin >> amaPrd;
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            cout << "--Linear------------" << endl;
            cout << "Program: 1234   |Box                 | 139.50|   1|kg        |   5|" << endl;
            cout << "  Yours: " << amaPrd << endl;
            cout << "--Form Display------" << endl;
            cout << "--Program: " << endl;
            cout << "Sku: 1234" << endl;
            cout << "Name : box" << endl;
            cout << "Price : 123.45" << endl;
            cout << "Price after tax : 139.50" << endl;
            cout << "Quantity On Hand : 1 kgs" << endl;
            cout << "Quantity Needed : 5" << endl;
            cout << "--Yours: " << endl;
            amaPrd.write(cout, false) << endl;
    }
    _pause();
    if (ok) {
            cout << "----Storage and loading test, the output of the Program and yours must match:" << endl;
            AmaProduct tprd;
            amaPrd.store(prdfile);
            amaPrd.store(prdfile);
            prdfile.close();
            cout << "--Store AmaProduct, program: " << endl
                    << "N,1234,box,123.45,1,1,kg,5" << endl
                    << "N,1234,box,123.45,1,1,kg,5" << endl;
            cout << "--Store AmaProduct, yours: " << endl;
            dumpFile("amaPrd.txt");
            cout << "--Load AmaProduct: " << endl;
            prdfile.open("amaPrd.txt", ios::in);
            prdfile.ignore(2);
            tprd.load(prdfile);
            cout << "Program: 1234   |box                 | 139.50|   1|kg        |   5|" << endl;
            cout << "  Yours: " << tprd << endl;
            prdfile.clear();
            prdfile.close();
    }return 0;
}
```

WHERE IT FAILS:

```
cout << "----Price validation test:" << endl;
            piv("abc", "abc", "abc", 'y', "abc");
            cin >> amaPrd;
            if (cin.fail()) {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
                    cout << "Passed!" << endl
                            << "Message shoule be:  Invalid Price Entry" << endl
                            << "Your Error message: " << amaPrd << endl;
            }
            else {
                    ok = false;
                    cout << "Price validation failed" << endl;
            }
```

I don't understand why mine fails the price validation. ("Price validation failed").

Comment: It seems almost ironic this is tagged with `debugging`, when that very activity will probably lead to your answer.

Comment: i think i may have to initialize p to 0 within the functions..

Comment: nvm that did not fix it

Comment: Lotta code there. Start at the beginning. Make sure you're reading the input correctly, then that you are storing the input correctly, then that you are using the input correctly.

Comment: i am thinking it has to do with the previous error message corrupting the next output

Comment: since it fails after pressing "enter" on the tax input

Comment: Fire up the debugger, my friend. Place a breakpoint before the program fails, then start stepping until you see variables being set to values you don't want. Then looks at what you wanted, what you got and adjust the code accordingly.